# XOR a checksum - duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the SQL query below:

```
create table checksumtable (name1 varchar(100),name2 varchar(100))
insert into checksumtable values ('Ian','Maria')
insert into checksumtable values ('Maria','Ian')
```

and the SQL below:

```
select checksum1^checksum2 as xorresult from (
select checksum(name1) as checksum1,checksum(name2) as checksum2 from checksumtable ) as checksumoutertable
```

The XORResult is the same for both rows.  I do not understand how this is the case.  I understand the principles and truth table of the XOR, however I do not understand how XORing the checksum produces the same result.

Answer (score 4):

XOR is a bitwise operator that doesn't care about the ordering of its arguments. A^B = B^A. `CHECKSUM` is always going to return the same value for "Ian" and it will always return the same value for "Maria", so:

```
CHECKSUM('Ian')^CHECKSUM('Maria') = CHECKSUM('Maria')^CHECKSUM('Ian')
```

Comment: Is it the same for OR gates; AND gates etc?

Comment: AND and OR are both commutative operators, so yes it would hold true for those as well.

Comment: Is there any reason you would choose an xor instead of an AND/OR.  The previous developer used XOR.  +1 for the response.

Comment: Keep in mind that `CHECKSUM` does allow for multiple parameters though, and that is not commutative, so `CHECKSUM('Ian', 'Maria') <> CHECKSUM('Maria', 'Ian')`

Comment: Without knowing what the code was supposed to be doing I can't even begin to guess what another developer might have been thinking. I find that even when I know what code is supposed to be doing I still can't even begin to guess what the previous developer was thinking... ;)

Comment: That is why you need the XOR? Why use an XOR instead of AND/OR?

Comment: My guess would be they were trying to implement a simple hashing function and didn't realize `CHECKSUM` can take more than one parameter - and didn't test using the same values in different orders.

Comment: Can you answer the question in my last comment before I mark this answer?

Comment: I have no idea why the developer would have coded it that way. As Dan Field suggests, it looks like it was probably a bug.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you saying that you should not xor a checksum like this? The developer was trying to find duplicate rows.  The two rows in the table from my op is a duplicate.